# How can I use numeric names in a PowerShell hash table?

Tags: powershell

When I create a hash table entry with a numeric name, it seems impossible to address it like I can when I use text strings for names.

[image]

Why is this? Is there a simple workaround, or is this error by design?

Comment: Could you possibly edit the question and put the text inside the question?  I cannot view your image but I can see the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the subscript operator `[]`:

```
# ~> $a[1]
One

# ~> $a["three"]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this must refer to an older version of PowerShell. In PowerShell v3 at any rate:

```
$a.1
```

produces the expected output, "One".

However, `$a.2` returns nothing, you have to do `$a.'2'`

Clearly, @zdan's answer is the preferred method if you really must mix up numbers with text.

An important point in any computer language is not to mix numbers and text unwittingly.